# Magento 2.4 modify search query (product name and short description)

Tags: search, magento2.4

I want to make changes to the search engine. I used magento 2.4. Currently, the main search engine searches by product name. I would like it to also search by short description.

What I mean:

maindomain.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=example_name

query must search for results in the product name and the short description.
Currently, it only searches by product name. And I want it to search by product name and short description

How to change it? Where in the code do I need to make changes?